# gradle issue after distribution 4.10.2

Tags: gradle, flutter

I follow all recommandation to make migration of androidX 
but when I change distribution

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

I have this error

```
The Gradle project does not define a task suitable for the requested build.
Review the android/app/build.gradle file and ensure it defines a debug build type.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'null' not found in root project 'android'.
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: Please add the action that triggered this - either the command line or the IDE item

Comment: This issue can happen if you are running a build (i.e. one of the gradle's task) in `parallel` mode. I got the same error using `Gradle 4.3.1` (where I'm running a task: ex: `gradle rpm` on 5 different projects in parallel mode in Jenkinsfile each having individual stage under `stages`. Re-running the same pipeline run with same parameters works next time and other times it fails intermittently with this error. I also got this error mesg too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797696/jenkins-2-176-4-3-rolling-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-last-unit-does-n