# Jenkins - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits & Gradle error: Task 'null' not found in root project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, parallel-processing, locking, jenkins-pipeline

**Jenkins** *2.176.4-3 rolling*

**Gradle** *4.3.1*

**Issue area**: **Parallel** run of a given *single* Gradle task (or it could be any simple action) **and** especially when running **concurrent runs** of *Jenkinsfile* based pipelines

All the sudden I got this error in Jenkins log page, **never seen this error before** (found no stackoverflow posts either for this error in Jenkins).

**Error:** **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits**

1. For some reason the previous build failed and automatically took me to Jenkins logs page showing Jenkins angry fire face: [image]
2. Re-ran **just one run** of Jenkinsfile pipeline again (which runs a single Gradle task (lets say: `rpm` task) present in multiple projects in parallel) and it worked successfully!!; **checked parameters/values** passed between successful and failed runs - they were similar.

**Example Jenkinsfile** can be found here: [Jenkinsfile Pipeline DSL: How to Show Multi-Columns in Jobs dashboard GUI - For all Dynamically created stages - When within PIPELINE section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885845/jenkinsfile-pipeline-dsl-how-to-show-multi-columns-in-jobs-dashboard-gui-for) where I'm running a gradle task (lets say `gradle rpm`) in parallel (each gradle `rpm` task running in individual `stage step`) by creating dynamic stages (so that I don't hard-code them in Jenkinsfile for each project).

**NOTE**: In Jenkinsfile, even though the gradle task `rpm` (that I'm running in parallel in individual `stage` (under `stages`) section has a valid gradle task defined i.e. `rpm`, **it seems like** Gradle task running on multiple projects in `parallel` (section within Jenkinsfile) is not 100% successful everytime, with at least `Gradle 4.3.1` as I'm also seeing this other error:

```
05:31:41 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
05:31:42 
05:31:42 * What went wrong:
05:31:42 Task 'null' not found in root project 'T000123_ABCD_Project'.
05:31:42
```

This issue poster said similar here: [gradle issue after distribution 4.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313510/gradle-issue-after-distribution-4-10-2)

Here is the **Full error log** in Jenkins stack trace is showing:

```
 Oops!

A problem occurred while processing the request.
        Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported.
        If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem.
        If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue.
        When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins.
        The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.
Stack trace

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:734)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at hudson.util.UnbufferedBase64InputStream.read(UnbufferedBase64InputStream.java:41)
    at hudson.util.UnbufferedBase64InputStream.read(UnbufferedBase64InputStream.java:53)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleNote.readFrom(ConsoleNote.java:258)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleAnnotationOutputStream.eol(ConsoleAnnotationOutputStream.java:111)
    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.eol(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:60)
    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.write(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:56)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.log.FileLogStorage$1$1.write(FileLogStorage.java:238)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:89)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.framework.io.LargeText$HeadMark.moveTo(LargeText.java:314)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.framework.io.LargeText.writeLogTo(LargeText.java:229)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.writeRawLogTo(AnnotatedLargeText.java:168)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.log.FileLogStorage$1.writeHtmlTo(FileLogStorage.java:203)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.writeLogTo(AnnotatedLargeText.java:147)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.framework.io.LargeText.doProgressText(LargeText.java:264)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.doProgressiveHtml(AnnotatedLargeText.java:95)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:797)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:219)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$9.dispatch(MetaClass.java:456)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.impl.cloudbees.UnrestrictedApiCallsMonitor$ApiMonitorFilter.doFilter(UnrestrictedApiCallsMonitor.java:120)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:243)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.slowrequest.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(SlowRequestFilter.java:37)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**What's making** me get this error message in Jenkins?

**Error:** **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits**

and

**Why my pipeline runs fail intermittently** with the following error message in **Gradle** (when `parallel` section is used to run something (i.e. a Gradle `someTask`) within `Jenkinsfile`)?

**Task 'null' not found in root project**

**When running** *many* **concurrent** runs of this pipeline (which runs a Gradle task on many projects in `parallel`), let's say I launch 4 pipelines runs and each is building 3-5 project's Gradle `rpm` task), then I saw the following issues related to FILE locking.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828842/1499296

**i.e. Gradle not able to delete folder/file (as listed below)**

```
**Execution failed for task ':clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /some/path/build/someFolder/aFolder_or_File **
```

or

**Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task due to Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache**

```
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':rpm' property 'archivePath' during up-to-date check.

> Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/view/user123456_Team_Tools/vobs/space/test/folder1/Project1of5/.gradle/4.3.1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

  Owner PID: 29003

  Our PID: 903

  Owner Operation: 

  Our operation: 

  Lock file: /view/user123456_Team_Tools/vobs/space/test/folder1/Project1of5/.gradle/4.3.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

or

getting: **Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()**

```
17:40:11 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:40:11 
17:40:11 * What went wrong:
17:40:11 Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
17:40:11 > Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
```

or

**Could not read path** 
 *'/some/jenkins/workspace/path/of/a/job/folder/sub-folder/file.class_or_any_extension'*

or

**java.io.FileNotFoundException** i.e. 
Not able to find a file (that Gradle is builds successfully if I run only one run of this pipeline).

```
17:38:28 * What went wrong:
17:38:28 Execution failed for task ':rpm'.
17:38:28 > java.io.FileNotFoundException: '/some/jenkins/workspace/path/of/a/job/folder/sub-folder/artifact-1.0.0.121.rpm'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At a single pipeline run case**, if you have even more projects (let's say 20+ projects) and you are running Gradle *someTask* in parallel (*whether in a single stage or individual stages per project*), then you could set `GRADLE_USER_HOME=$WORKSPACE/${whichProject}` folder (where `${whichProject}` is a project folder which will be available to you in Jenkins `WORKSPACE` (after `git clone` or *similar checkout* operation)). This could possibly solve any `parallel` task running into any locking related issues but at the cost of compromising Gradle's performance (i.e. for not using Gradle CACHE among many project's parallel task run).

Setting a unique **GRADLE_USER_HOME** value (per project) inside dynamically created unique Jenkins workspace (**example**: `/jenkins/workspaces/jobname/<buildnumber>/` where BUILD_NUMBER makes the Jenkins workspace folder unique) will resolve any **lock** related issues

1. i.e. Doing this, ***Project1*** will use `GRADLE_USER_HOME=/jenkins/workspaces/jobname/<buildnumber>/Project1` (and now `.gradle` and `caches` folders will sit under this folder and used by Gradle and won't collide with other project's Gradle CACHE folder: `.gradle` and `caches` which are also running in parallel).

I noticed **CLI option** `--gradle-user-home` (aka $GRADLE_USER_HOME) while running Gradle task was getting set to just Jenkins's WORKSPACE **example value** only and thus, all 3-5 project's Gradle task (in my case `rpm` task) runs were running in `parallel` (using the same service account's Gradle `caches` folder) which usually sits under GRADLE_USER_HOME location (so in my case single Gradle's `caches` folder was getting shared by all those 3-5 projects for parallel task run).

I'm still trying to find the solution for **When running concurrent pipeline runs** (which again runs `parallel` Gradle `rpm` task per project within a single pipeline run) *each using their own* ***different*** Jenkins **WORKSPACE** folders, why I'm still getting these issues; I'll update if I find a solution.